# A graph $G$ such that $iγ(G)=1, γ^E(G)=100$.

Tags: graph-theory

Given a graph $G$, and a subset $A$ of $V(G)$, define $γ(A)$ = size of minimal dominating set for $A$ in $G$.

Define $I(G)$ = The set of independent sets of vertices in G (a subset $A$ of $V(G)$ is independent if no two vertices in A are connected by an edge)
Define $iγ(G) = \max_{A \in I(G)} γ(A)$
Define $γ^E(G)$ = size of a minimal dominating set by edges for $G$ (every edge $e={a,b}$ dominates $N(a) \cup N(b)$)

I need to find a graph such that $iγ(G)=1$, $γ^E(G)=100$.
I tried all sorts of different graphs, but i did not came very far.
Any ideas?

Comment: Hopefully I'm not misunderstanding, but does a union of stars work?

Comment: I don't see why it helps, because there might be independent sets that cannot be controlled by a single vertex.

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I did misunderstand. So if $A \in I(G)$, definitionally none of the vertices in $A$ are connected. So if $A$ is an independent set of vertices, $\gamma (A) = |A|$. So if $i_{\gamma}(G) = 1$, the largest size of an independent set is 1. So your graph has to be the complete graph on $n$ vertices for some $n$. Now in order to force $\gamma^{E}(G) = 100$, we take $n=200$. $(x_1, x_2), (x_3,x_4), \cdots, (x_{2k-1}, x_{2k}) , \cdots , (x_{199},x_{200})$ is a minimal dominating set by edges for $G$.

Comment: $\gamma(A)$ might be smaller then $|A|$ because maybe every vertex in $A$ is connected to some $v \not \in A$.

Comment: Ah sorry I just keep misunderstanding...

Comment: At the risk of further embarrassing myself...does my example not still work, modulo my initial statement that you refute? 

If G is the complete graph on $200$ vertices, independent sets are size 1, so $\gamma$ is $1$ for every independent set, and $\gamma^{E}(G) = 100$.

Comment: Any edge dominates it's vertices and all of their neighbors, and so in your example one edge dominates the whole complete graph.

Comment: ah bleh was thinking like in this sense https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_dominating_set for the def of $\gamma^{E}(G)$

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I thought about it intermittently for awhile. I couldn't even write down a graph with $i_{\gamma}(G)=1$ and $\gamma^E(G)>1$...